# Delete files from dir

Tags: java

I'm writing some files to a folder.

But when I reuse that folder I want to delete every file in that directory. The problem is that I don't know if this directory actually exists or not.

```
final String fileDir = "myPath/someDir/;
// If this dir exists, delete every file inside
//Populate this dir ( I have this code)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create directory. If exists, delete directory and its content and create new one in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835285/create-directory-if-exists-delete-directory-and-its-content-and-create-new-one)

Comment: but I have a string, not a file.

Comment: `File file = new File(fileDir);` You can pass the String to file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a proper way to check for file/directory existence in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996524/is-there-a-proper-way-to-check-for-file-directory-existence-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This the way to check if file exists

```
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // delete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `package java.nio.file` you have very handy utils (from java7):

```
Files.deleteIfExists(path)
```

and if you want to delete recursively sth like:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/your/dir");
Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

   @Override
   public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes) throws IOException {
       Files.delete(file);
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
   }

   @Override
   public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path directory, IOException exception) throws IOException {
       Files.delete(directory);
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` class

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory);
```

There is this method available in the same file. This will also recursively deletes all sub-folders and files under them.

```
final String fileDir = "myPath/someDir/";
File dir = new File(fileDir);
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
```

Comment: it expects a file not a string with the dir

Comment: Create a file object out of it. new File("myPath/someDir");

Comment: I got error saying the dir doesn't exist (and it doesn't). i just need an if `if(dir.exists()` ??

Comment: This is the basic thing that you need to change the path to actual directory path. :O